# How to check parent of specified theme?

Tags: android

I want to check if specified theme is parent of `Theme.AppCompat`.

For example:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat" />
```

And now function:

```
public boolean checkTheme(int theme, int parent)
{
      // TODO: Implement method for check if theme is parent of another theme
      // now I don't know how to do this

      return false;
}

checkTheme(R.style.AppTheme, R.style.Theme_AppCompat); // in that case should return true
```

Can I do it?

If yes, how to do this?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. A theme is just a set of styles. There is now way to get information about how this set is created. But it is an interesting question!

Comment: I want to create window overlay service and publish it and I want to detect if theme is parent of AppCompat and use different LayoutInflater e.g I want to replace EditText with AppCompatEditText.

Comment: @passsy I want to create window overlay service and publish it and I want to detect if theme is parent of AppCompat and use different LayoutInflater e.g I want to replace EditText with AppCompatEditText.

Comment: So your app is using different themes or do you want the theme of an activity of another app?

Comment: @passsy I want to create a service and overlay system window. If it's not possible I will add the method called `setThemeAppCompat(boolean)` and developer must call this method before inflating views.

Comment: @passsy PS. This is library project. I don't know what theme developer will use.

Comment: this method will be the easiest solution. I saw such libs and some of them provided binaries for both themes. Personally I would only support AppCompat. Most projects use it.

Comment: @passy Yes I know. I can check the AppCompat classes.  However I don't know if developer want to use AppCompat views. So I create this method.

Comment: You can try to retrieve theme attributes that are AppCompat-specific. If you get a value then AppCompat is probably used.